# Наименьший простой делитель

Tags: python

Мой код:

```
n = int(input())
i = 2
while n % i != 0:
    i += 1
print(i)
```

Минимальный простой делитель
Дано целое число, не меньшее 2. Выведите его наименьший простой делитель.

Входные данные: целое положительное число N≤2∗109
Выходные данные: выведите ответ на задачу.

Примеры:
15 -> 3
179 -> 179

Пишет: Программа выдаёт ошибку в процессе выполнения
Подсказка: Для сокращения времени работы программы организуйте цикл, перебирающий делители до N−−√. Написать его можно таким образом:

```
while i * i <= N:
```

Как решить?

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
i = 2
stop = n ** 0.5 # (0.5 степень) == квадратный корень.
# Посчитано заранее, чтобы на каждой итерации заново не считать i * i

while i < stop and n % i != 0:
    i += 1

print(i if n % i == 0 else n)
# Если n всё еще не делится на i, значит не нашлось, число простое.
```